# Анимация линии при наведении

Tags: svg

Как сделать анимацию линии при наведении на весь блок? 
И чтобы анимация срабатывала обратно при отведении курсора с блока. 
Вот как сейчас сделал:

```html
<div class="record-block">
  <a href="#" class="recording">Запись на примерку
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 222 38" style="enable-background:new 0 0 222 38;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0 {
  fill: #bd2486;
  filter: url(#violet-fill);
}
.st1 {
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.st2 {
  fill: #E6E6E6;
}
</style>
<filter id="violet-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
<feFlood flood-color="#000"/>
<feOffset dx="8.2112">
<animate id="anim" attributeName="dx" values="0;10;0" dur="3s" begin="path1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/>
</feOffset>
<feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
<feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
<g id="ink">
<g>
<g>
<path id="path1" class="st0" d="M35.5,20.6c-0.2-0.4-1.3-2.4-1.6-2.7c-0.7-0.6-1.5-0.8-2.2-0.5c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.4-0.8,0.7l-0.3,0.7
c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.5,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.6-0.7,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-1.3,0.6c-0.6,0.1-1.2-0.2-1.5-0.6C26.2,20.2,26,19.7,26,19
c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2v-0.1v-0.2v-0.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.2c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.6-0.6c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.1,0
s-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2l-0.1,0.1l-0.1,0.3c-0.2,0.4-0.6,0.8-1,1c-0.8,0.4-2,0.3-2.7-0.5
c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6s-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5C20.1,15.6,20,15.3,20,15c-0.1-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.2-1.8s-0.1-1.1-0.1-1.6
c0-0.1,0-0.2-0.1-0.2c0-0.1,0,0,0.2,0.1c0.2,0,0,0,0,0h-0.1c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.5-0.4,1s-0.1,1,0,1.5c0.2,2.1,0.7,4.6,1.4,6.7
l-1.3,0.5c-0.6-2.2-1.2-4.4-1.4-6.7c0-0.6-0.1-1.2,0-1.8s0.2-1.4,0.9-2c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.3c0.3,0,0.4-0.1,0.9,0
c0.4,0.2,0.6,0.5,0.7,0.7s0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6c0.1,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.2,1.8c0.1,0.5,0.1,1.1,0.3,1.5c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7
c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0.1,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c0,0,0,0,0-0.1l0.1-0.3
c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5c0.2-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.9-1s1-0.3,1.5-0.2c1,0.2,1.5,0.9,1.9,1.5s0.6,1.3,0.6,2c0,0.3,0,0.7,0,1
c0,0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.5v0.3v0.1l0,0c0-0.1,0,0,0,0l0,0c0,0,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.6s0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8
c0.4-0.7,1-1.2,1.7-1.5c1.5-0.6,3.1,0,4.1,0.9c0.5,0.5,0.9,1,1.2,1.6c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.9c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5l0.1,0.4
c0.3,0.9,0.9,1.8,1.5,2.6c0.7,0.8,1.4,1.6,2.3,2.2c1.7,1.3,3.7,2,5.9,2.1v1c-2.4,0.1-4.7-0.6-6.7-1.9c-1-0.7-1.9-1.5-2.6-2.4
C36.6,22.8,35.9,21.8,35.5,20.6"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<rect x="45.8" y="27" class="st0" width="8.7" height="1"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path class="st1" d="M18.5,19.5"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path class="st1" d="M20.1,23.4"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path class="st0" d="M20.7,20.7c0.3,0.9,0.6,1.7,0.7,2.7s-0.1,2.1-1,3c-0.4,0.4-1.1,0.7-1.7,0.8c-0.6,0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.4
c-1.1-0.6-1.6-1.7-1.9-2.7l1.9-0.4c0.1,0.6,0.5,1.2,1,1.5c0.4,0.3,1,0.3,1.3,0c0.4-0.3,0.6-1,0.6-1.7s-0.2-1.5-0.4-2.3L20.7,20.7
z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path class="st0" d="M15,24.1c-1.1-3.5-1.2-6.2-1.3-9.7c0-0.9,0-1.8,0-2.6v-1.3c0-0.3,0-0.7-0.2-1c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.4-0.6
c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3,0c-0.3,0.2-0.6,1-0.6,1.8h-1.4L10.7,10c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0.1-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.9-1.5
c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.4,1-0.4s0.8,0.1,1.1,0.2c0.6,0.3,0.9,0.9,1.2,1.4c0.2,0.5,0.3,1.1,0.3,1.6v1.3c0,0.9,0.1,1.7,0.1,2.6
c0.2,3.4,0.3,6.1,1.4,9.3L15,24.1z"></path>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path class="st0" d="M12.1,9.5c0.2,0.6,0.1,1.1,0.1,1.7v1.7c0,1.1-0.1,2.2,0,3.4c0.1,2.2,0.2,4.5,0.3,6.7l-1,0.1
c-0.2-2.2-0.4-4.5-0.6-6.7c-0.1-1.1-0.1-2.3-0.2-3.4c0-0.6,0-1.1,0-1.7c0-0.6,0-1.1,0.1-1.7h1.3C12.1,9.6,12.1,9.5,12.1,9.5z"></path>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<path class="st0" d="M12.5,23c0,0.8,0.1,1.5,0.1,2.3s0,1.6-0.4,2.5c-0.7,1.8-2.9,2.8-4.8,2c-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.2-0.9L6,28.6
l-0.2-0.3l-0.3-0.5c-0.4-0.7-0.8-1.4-1.1-2.2c-0.6-1.5-1-3-1.3-4.5S2.7,18,2.6,16.5c0-1.6,0-3.1,0.2-4.6c0.3-3.1,1-6.1,1.9-9
l0.7,0.2C4.7,6,4.3,9,4.2,12c-0.1,3,0.2,5.9,0.7,8.8C5.2,22.2,5.6,23.6,6,25c0.3,0.7,0.5,1.3,0.9,1.9S7.5,28,8,28.2
c0.9,0.5,2.3,0,2.8-1c0.3-0.5,0.4-1.3,0.5-2s0.1-1.5,0.2-2.2H12.5z"></path>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>

<rect x="11.4" y="22.2" transform="matrix(0.9978 -6.658242e-02 6.658242e-02 0.9978 -1.5019 0.8433)" class="st0" width="1" height="1.5"></rect>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g id="Layer_3">
<g>
<path d="M67.5,27.7c0.3-0.4,0.5-0.6,0.8-0.9c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1h0.4l1.6-0.1l3.3-0.1v0.2l0.9,1l-0.9,1v0.2l-3.3-0.1l-1.6-0.1
h-0.4c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4-0.1C68,28.3,67.8,28,67.5,27.7z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path class="st2" d="M74.1,25.3c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.7v3.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.7c4.3,1.5,47.6,2.5,53.9,2.6
c0.4,0,0.8-0.3,0.8-0.7v-6.5c0-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.7-0.7C121.7,24.5,81.1,24.6,74.1,25.3z"></path>
<path d="M127.8,32.5c-6.4-0.1-49.6-1.1-53.9-2.6c-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.4-0.7V26c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.6-0.8c7-0.7,48.1-0.8,53.8-0.7
c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5,0.1s0.3,0.4,0.3,0.6v6.5C128.6,32.2,128.2,32.5,127.8,32.5z M74.1,25.3c-0.3,0-0.6,0.3-0.6,0.7v3.2
c0,0.2,0,0.5,0.4,0.7c4.3,1.5,47.5,2.5,53.9,2.6c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7v-6.5c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1l0,0
C122.2,24.6,81.1,24.6,74.1,25.3L74.1,25.3z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path class="st2" d="M128.5,25.5c8.5,0.1,81.1,0,89.3,0c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.8v4.5c0,0.4-0.3,0.8-0.8,0.8h-89.2V25.5z"></path>
<path d="M217.7,31.7h-89.3v-6.4h0.1c6.7,0.1,53.8,0,76.5,0c6.4,0,11.1,0,12.8,0c0.5,0,0.8,0.4,0.8,0.9v4.5
C218.6,31.3,218.3,31.7,217.7,31.7z M128.6,31.5h89.1c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7v-4.5c0-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.6-0.7c-1.8,0-6.4,0-12.8,0
c-22.5,0-69.2,0.1-76.4,0V31.5z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<defs>
<path id="SVGID_1_" d="M128.5,27c8.5,0.1,81.1,0,89.3,0c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.6V31c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.8,0.6h-89.2V27z"></path>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
<use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
</clipPath>
<g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);">
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="91" height="5" xlink:href="75FACFF6.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 128 27)">
</image>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<defs>
<path id="SVGID_3_" d="M218.5,28c-8.5,0-81.1,0-89.3,0c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-0.7-0.3v-1.9c0-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.8-0.3h89.2V28z"></path>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
<use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
</clipPath>
<g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);">
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="91" height="3" xlink:href="75FACFFA.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 128 25)">
</image>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<defs>
<path id="SVGID_5_" d="M74.1,27.4c-0.3,0-0.6,0.2-0.6,0.4v1.8c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.4c4.3,0.9,47.6,2.4,53.9,2.5
c0.4,0,0.8-0.2,0.8-0.4v-3.6c0-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4C121.7,28,81.1,27,74.1,27.4z"></path>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
<use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
</clipPath>
<g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);">
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="56" height="6" xlink:href="75FACFFD.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73 27)">
</image>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<defs>
<path id="SVGID_7_" d="M74,25.3c-0.3,0-0.6,0.7-0.6,0.8v1.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3c4.3,0.5,47.7,0.6,53.9,0.4
c0.4,0,0.7-0.2,0.7-0.3l-0.1-2.8c0-0.2-0.3-0.6-0.8-0.6C121.7,24.7,81,24.8,74,25.3z"></path>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
<use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
</clipPath>
<g style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_8_);">
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="56" height="7" xlink:href="75FACFFE.png" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73 23)">
</image>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<rect x="128.3" y="25.4" width="0.5" height="6.2"></rect>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M130,27c14.5-0.1,29-0.1,43.5-0.1s29,0,43.5,0.1c-14.5,0.1-29,0.1-43.5,0.1S144.5,27.1,130,27z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M74,27.3c8.2-0.2,16.5-0.3,24.7-0.4s16.5-0.2,24.7-0.2c-8.2,0.2-16.5,0.3-24.7,0.4C90.5,27.2,82.3,27.3,74,27.3z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M78.5,28.2c4.2-0.1,8.3-0.1,12.5-0.1h12.5l12.5,0.1c4.2,0.1,8.3,0.2,12.5,0.3c-4.2,0.1-8.3,0.1-12.5,0.1h-12.5L91,28.5
C86.8,28.4,82.7,28.3,78.5,28.2z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M85.5,29.1c5,0,10,0.1,15,0.1c5,0.1,10,0.2,15,0.4c-5,0-10-0.1-15-0.1C95.5,29.3,90.5,29.3,85.5,29.1z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M144.5,28c5.4-0.1,10.8-0.2,16.3-0.2l16.3-0.1l16.3,0.1c5.4,0,10.8,0.1,16.3,0.2c-5.4,0.1-10.8,0.2-16.3,0.2H177
l-16.3-0.1C155.3,28.2,149.9,28.1,144.5,28z"></path>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M165.5,29c5.4-0.1,10.8-0.1,16.3-0.1c5.4,0,10.8,0,16.3,0.1c-5.4,0.1-10.8,0.1-16.3,0.1S170.9,29.1,165.5,29z"></path>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
```